# Как сохранить значение input после перенаправления на другую страницу $_POST?

Tags: php, post

Вот у меня есть форма.

```js
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if(!empty($_POST['name']) and !empty($_POST['age'])) {
    $var_value = $_POST['name'];
    if($_POST['age'] >= 21) {
      header('Location: maxage.php');
    } else {
      header('Location: minage.php');
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Заполните все поля';
  }
}
Когда я отправляю с заполненным именем и возрастом 21+, я перехожу на maxage.php
и там я хочу вывести банально echo $_POST['name']; но там пусто в var_dump NULL как мне сохранить это значение.
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  name<input type="text" name="name" class="<?=  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and empty($_POST['name'])) ? 'invalid' : ''?>">
   <p><input type="submit" /></p>

  age <input type="number" name="age" class="<?=  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and empty($_POST['age'])) ? 'invalid' : ''?>">
</form>
```

Чет сложно, максимум как получилось вывести значение inputa после перенаправления.

```js
if($_POST['age'] >= 21) {
      $link='maxage.php?name='.$_POST['name'];
        header('location:'.$link);
    }
```

и уже в maxage.php, через echo $_GET['name'] я смог получить простой вывод имени.
Но это GET, +он в url заносится при этом способе. Через $_POST я даже не понимаю почему оно не сохраняется при переходе на другую страницу.

Answer (score 1):

При вызове `header('location:')` происходит редирект на другой адрес и естественно массив $_POST туда не передается. Вам или передавать GET или отправлять пост но с помощью родных функций [socket](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-socket-client) или расширения [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.curl.php). Но сомневаюсь что Вам в этом случаи нужно отправлять пост (так как Вы его уже отправили с формы и в данный момент обрабатываете, зачем его ещё пересылать?!) или нужна переадресация с `header location`, достаточно простого [include](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)

```
if($_POST['age'] >= 21) {
  include 'maxage.php';
} else {
  include 'minage.php';
}
```

Comment: Когда я так делаю, я остаюсь на своей странице с формой без перехода.
и над формой я вижу сообщение свое echo "Добро пожаловть " . $_POST['name']; и тут подставляется значение. Я хочу на maxage.php попасть и там уже вывод делать.

Comment: Для этого форму вынесите отдельно в другой от обработчика файл и не будет таких проблем или же поставьте проверку на пост. Естественно если не ставить условия на проверку поста в основном файле, будет показываться форма. У Вас уже стоит условие ( if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  )допишите к нему else и вставьте в него форму

Comment: Видимо что-то не так делаю, вынес то что в теге form в другой файл, но в нем я подключил через inlude свой php код обработчика. Когда жму submit если возраст 21 + попадаю на maxage/ но значение $_POST['name'] пустое. Сложна

Comment: Просто в Вашем файле в условии if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') добавьте else и вынесете форму в него

Comment: сделал так если я правильно тебя понял else {
 include 'formdz.php';
}.  
Вот теперь при отправке я перехожу на нужный файл в зависимости от возраста и там выводит мое введеное значение $_POST. Но появилась другая проблема, если у меня не заполненные все поля, у меня раньше форма оставалась на станице и подсвечивалось, там class добавляется. теперь просто echo = заполните все поля, и нужно жать кнопку назад чтобы вернуться назад к форме. f5 не обновляет страницу.

Comment: вместо всех этих страданий тебе надо было просто нормально изложить **исходную** задачу. а сейчас у тебя весь диалог это "доктор, я сую палец в дисковую пилу, и его мне отрывает нахрен. как мне так сунуть чтобы не отрывало?"

Comment: @Ипатьев да вроде все просто, есть поле инпута name=name и нужно чтобы это значение вывелось на другой странице после отправки формы. Че тут сложного в задаче,  у меня просто не получается как у новичка, либо я не знаю нюансов языка.

Comment: @faradei не нужна тебе другая страница, выводи на той же.

Comment: @Ипатьев условие задачи, если поля заполнены, новое условие на возраст и там 2 варианта, 21+ или 21- и взавимимости от этого переадресация на другую страницу, а на ней вывод, введеных значений  в инпут. Ты рофлишь или что, на этой странице я бы давно вывел.

Comment: @faradei ну вообще да, и не я один. тут пол-интернета укатывается над твоими страданиями. что-то не бьется эта задача свтоим кодом. здесь ты пишешь что новое условие **после** отправки формы, а в коде у тебя оба условия сразу в форме. у тебя есть исходный текст задания, ты можешь его процитировать, а не своими словами коряво пересказывать?

Comment: @Ипатьев Условие необходимо создать форму с полями name и age.
При отправке проверяйте поля на заполенение, если введеные поля заполнены, проверить введный возраст. Если возраст больше 21, переадресуйте его на страницу содержащую текст Добро пожаловть username, где username имя введенное в форму. Если какоето из полей не заполнено подсветите эти поля и выведите сообщения об ошибке. Я сделал 90% задачи просто не знаю как на другой странице вывести введенно значание после отправи формы.

Comment: @faradei дебильная какая-то задача. ну в общем либо как ты уже делал - редирект с передачей имени в адресной строке, либо сессии. Либо все проверки и подсветки яваскриптом, а в пхп только вывод. Либо без всяких редиректов - всё делать в одном и том же скрипте, но тогда это криво, потому что после успешного POST-а **всегда** делается редирект. там точно форма должна быть методом пост?

Comment: @Ипатьев я короче потом ещё спрошу у знакомого пхпшера, а сам дальше по материалу пойду, а то я устал это решать, я уверен что мне не весь материал дали для норм решения, сессии, куки я по сути не изучал. делал как знаю.

Comment: @faradei ну если вы еще ничего не проходили, ты уверен что форма должне быть методом пост? В задании об этом ничего нет

Comment: @Ипатьев об этом не сказано, я просто сам начал через post делать. Так как если GET делать то в адрессной строке хранятся значения, я хотел типо скрытно сделать. Просто если будет 3ое поле пароль, как то не очень будет с GET

Comment: @faradei а при чем здесь пароль? Когда просят пароль, не запрашивают возраст. И без сессий пароль все равно не имеет смысла. Не беги впереди паровоза

Comment: @Ипатьев просто предположил так.

Comment: @faradei ну в общем ты мыслишь верно а задача дебильная. Впрочем в процессе ее решения ты многое узнал, то есть свою задачу оно в какой-то мере выполнило.

Answer (score -1):

Тебе - **никак**

Сами по себе данные POST при редиректе не передаются.

Редирект - это просто рекомендация браузеру запросить какую-либо ссылку, как будто ты ее руками ввел в адресную строку.

Их можно запомнить в сессию, но в твоем случае это не нужно, а нужно просто нормально организовать код в скрипте-обработчике формы.

Comment: почему никак, зачем мне тогда мне дали такое задание после урока, если по той инфе что я получил, перепробовав кучу вариантов, при отправке формы, с переходом на другую страницу, значение $_post[] не сохраняется, хотят тут парень мне помог, немного подкоректировать код, я тоже изначально делал include место header(location). но немного налажал.  

А про сессии куки я не изучал, один чувак вообще ссылку на json дал.

Comment: потому что ты не понял задание. и не можешь даже его толком воспроизвести." есть поле инпута name=name и нужно чтобы это значение вывелось на другой странице после отправки формы" - это детский лепет, а не задание, и решается вообще безо всех этих твоих мучений.

Comment: я понял задание, просто не правильно написал решение, я же не знал что при переходе на другую страницу у меня ничего не выведется и значения инпутов не сохранятся, чел я в пхп бувально несколько часов.